# Someone's going to have to clean this up

Tags: discussion, fun, unicorns, april-fools

Wow, that was one heck of an April Unicorn's Day party. But now that it's April 2nd in UTC land, look at this place. It's trashed. There is unicorn crap everywhere. I don't know how many people OD'd on rainbows. And I doubt I'm the only one that woke up next to a donkey that I was *positive* was a unicorn yesterday. Say we close it all as "no longer relevant", hide it, and delete it. Someone from the outside might start asking questions. Rumors will circulate. "WHAT REALLY HAPPENED ON META STACK OVERFLOW??" "WHY ISN'T JEFF ATWOOD TALKING??" They'll do some investigative searching. Some scientists will come into the server room with UV lights, and discover glowing spots everywhere. GCMS analysis will reveal it to be similar to pony DNA, but a little more magical. "ARE THE METIZENS HIDING THE TRUTH ABOUT UNICORNS??" Maybe someone will come forward, hiding like a coward behind community-wiki. "INFORMANT SPEAKS: CLAIMS KNOWLEDGE OF APRIL 1 EVENTS"  Before he can speak, his account will be banned. Disaster averted, but there will be more. What then? We can't possibly stop them all. Eventually, word will get out. Our friends and family will find out what happened here, and they will never look at us the same way. Jobs will be lost. Families will be broken. Some may even plunge a unicorn horn right through their own hearts. Was it worth it? WAS IT WORTH IT?

````
                                                   /
                                                  .7
                                       \       , //
                                       |\.--._/|//
                                      /\ ) ) ).'/
                                     /(  \  // /
                                    /(   J`((_/ \
                                   / ) | _\     /
                                  /|)  \  eJ    L
                                 |  \ L \   L   L
                                /  \  J  `. J   L
                                |  )   L   \/   \
                               /  \    J   (\   /
             _....___         |  \      \   \```
      ,.._.-'        '''--...-||\     -. \   \
    .'.=.'                    `         `.\ [ Y
   /   /                                  \]  J
  Y / Y                                    Y   L
  | | |          \                         |   L
  | | |           Y                        A  J
  |   I           |                       /I\ /
  |    \          I             \        ( |]/|
  J     \         /._           /        -tI/ |
   L     )       /   /'-------'J           `'-:.
   J   .'      ,'  ,' ,     \   `'-.__          \
    \ T      ,'  ,'   )\    /|        ';'---7   /
     \|    ,'L  Y...-' / _.' /         \   /   /
      J   Y  |  J    .'-'   /         ,--.(   /
       L  |  J   L -'     .'         /  |    /\
       |  J.  L  J     .-;.-/       |    \ .' /
       J   L`-J   L____,.-'`        |  _.-'   |
        L  J   L  J                  ``  J    |
        J   L  |   L                     J    |
         L  J  L    \                    L    \
         |   L  ) _.'\                    ) _.'\
         L    \('`    \                  ('`    \
          ) _.'\`-....'                   `-....'
         ('`    \
          `-.___/   sk
````

Comment: One of the diamonds will go through and delete them all one by one. So, eventually.

Comment: It was worth it just to get a glimpse of ASCIIcorn.

Comment: @Kip: actually, i'm nearly *positive* you're the only one who woke up next to a donkey you thought was a unicorn yesterday.

Answer (score 15):

> Was it worth it? WAS IT WORTH IT?

It was worth it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm compiling a list of unicorn-related questions that are being deleted, so 10k users can look back upon them fondly. This is definitely incomplete, so please add the ones that I missed:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45118/someone-hacked-my-account-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45027/what-happens-if-you-throw-a-black-gem-at-a-white-unicorn-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45014/sometimes-my-gravatar-shows-wrong-picture-why-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45004/problem-with-my-unicorn-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44997/who-has-the-best-unicorn-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44968/horrendous-unicorn-bug-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/why-has-no-one-realized-unicorns-have-wings-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44831/my-little-pony-cyberterrorism-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44789/i-dont-like-my-kornz-i-can-haz-another-one-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44925/the-picture-on-the-profile-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45196/how-can-i-man-up-my-gravatar-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45007/how-can-i-add-robocop-riding-my-unicorn-avatar-closed
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44820/how-can-i-switch-to-a-cuter-unicorn
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45037/why-is-my-avatar-suddenly-a-gay-horse
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44966/why-is-my-avatar-suddenly-a-gay-horse

Answer (score 5):

No disassemble, Stephanie!

It'll fall off the front page like every other joke. Assuming, that is, that people actually post stuff that's not meta meta...

<sup>thingadongdong</sup>

Comment: *Some* of us think it's time to move to meta-meta-meta, and discuss the appropriateness of discussing the appropriateness of discussings unicorns on a site devoted to discussing ponies that symbolize horses that are a metaphor for programming.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they could just leave all the Unicorn Gravatars where they are, or just run a script to rid the Overflow world of all unicorn references.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay. Plunging a unicorn horn through your own heart just makes you bleed rainbows and sunshine. Also, you sparkle like a teenage vampire and sometimes get mild gas.