# Deleted Meta Questions Archive

Tags: support, meta, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, archive

Some keep deleting questions with a lot of discussion, both relevant and/or historical, and we can't search on deleted questions.  Some of them are locked so that they cannot be undeleted, so I'm putting this question out, for links to be posted, so that those 10ks who want to find them in the future can.  I think topical will be the best way to organize it.

**What is a Community without History?**

> See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list for deleted questions on other sites *(for 10k users)*

Comment: Do deleted posts show up in the data dump? This seems like a spectacularly bad way to solve this problem

Comment: @Michael: no, they don't. Not unless they managed to *not* be deleted when the data was dumped.

Comment: @Michael, there's always the possibility a question was asked late in a month and not deleted until the beginning of the next month....

Comment: @Lance **Blissful**

Comment: Now I want to read all these, and I can't :(

Comment: @Michael, that's called motivation.  You should save the link to this question in case they delete it.

Comment: Anyone care to dig up all the deleted april-fools-unicorn posts?

Comment: Yet another spark to feed the flame war...

Comment: @Ivo, I don't really want flame wars, I just want to keep aware of context and history, this would all be meaningless if they would just implement 'isdeleted' for 10ks.

Comment: @jon there's an extra question for those somewhere

Comment: @devinb is no fun (see edits).

Comment: @Jon B, Apparently these days I am. Sorry buddy.

Comment: Is this just for MSO? If not, then *maybe*, from SO: [Surprise for a programmer on Birthday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420689/surprise-for-a-programmer-on-birthday/)

Comment: @Arjan, Yes, this is just for MSO.

Comment: Added *[Does Jon Skeet cheat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81836/does-jon-skeet-cheat)* as, were it posted on a Friday, I think it would have made a fine diversion for the folks here.  Plus I spent far too long on my answer to let it languish in the database.

Comment: What would happen if I deleted the 'Deleted Questions Archive'?

Comment: @Ivo, that would truly suck, at a black hole level.

Comment: @Ivo To our luck, [we already have it in the Archives for when that happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-questions-archive/61225#61225 "Though, access at that point probably becomes something of a Catch 22...")

Comment: For users under 10k, I've written a user script that will allow you to see view many of these questions, though not their answers. [Read more or install it from Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/q/2505/4112).

Comment: @Shog9 so they *won't* show up in data dump? *Huh?!* ***Why?!*** (what good is an incomplete dump?!)

Comment: @Lix The linked question was what prompted the rename.  I believe that all the questions linked directly in this question are on meta, while the ones in the (newly renamed) [Popular Deleted SO/SU/Programmers Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455) are linking to non-meta sites.  Having "Deleted Questions Archive" and "Popular Deleted Questions List" without further disambiguation seemed wrong.

Comment: @bla - right... didn't catch that...

Comment: Surely the existance of this archive suggests there is demand to be able to search on deleted questions

Comment: I am missing the "What Stack Overflow is not" meta post. I don't think it is among the referenced question in the answers here.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum It's in the "Discussion" answer.

Answer (score 22):

#### BUGS to be swept under the rug

- [Envelope lighting up arbitrarily and unpredictably](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/envelope-lighting-up-arbitrarily-and-unpredictably)
- [Why isn't XSL shown as a tag synonym for XSLT on the "info" tab when it appears in the list of tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61408/why-isnt-xsl-shown-as-a-tag-synonym-for-xslt-on-the-info-tab-when-it-appears-i)
- [Eeeek! What happened to my envelope?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)
- [Why Don't We Get Our Reputation Back After Properly Voting Down a Question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86806/why-dont-we-get-our-reputation-back-after-properly-voting-down-a-question)
- [Can We Please Stop Breaking Javascript?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88936/can-we-please-stop-breaking-javascript-closed)
- [What Happened To The Author Info Avatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105882/what-happened-to-the-author-info-avatar)
- [So We Can't Report Bugs Anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105890/so-we-cant-report-bugs-anymore)
- [Whats With the Dash In Certain Vote Counts In the SO Election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76552/whats-with-the-dash-in-certain-vote-counts-in-the-so-election)
- [Is Stack Overflow down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137543/is-stack-overflow-down)
- [Edits of Deleted Questions Don't Appear in a Users Activity History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56813/edits-of-deleted-questions-dont-appear-in-a-users-activity-history)
- [Should Absolute Timestamps Have Leading Zero On Hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59343/should-absolute-timestamps-have-leading-zero-on-hours)

Comment: FWIW, I love it that the first question involves the envelope not working properly, and the last involves it being removed...

Comment: @Shog, I hope people don't go up in arms about the 'EEk' question being deleted.  It was asked at a time when the functionality of the new feature was not 100% there and doesn't represent things as they are now.

Comment: @jinguy, There's no really good excuse to them deleting discussion questions like that.  The discussion will always be valid, even if things change.

Comment: @Lance, that question can be confusing.  If someone ends up finding it, it contains lots of mis-information now.

Comment: @jjnguy: there is still no link to users/recent, therefore the Eeeek bug report is still accurate. The only confusing thing here is why the powers-that-be think deleting massively-upvoted questions is ever a good idea. Closed, yes. Locked, if you must. But deleted = let's pretend this never happened = way more harm than any question could ever hope to wreak.

Comment: @Marti, that bug report does still have some valid information.  I agree.  However, it is filled with people complaining that they are missing features that are actually there now.

Comment: @jjn: Is that not precisely what the "Too Localized" close reason is for?  Why delete it?

Comment: @Aarobot, because Jeff felt it would do more harm than good by being around I guess.  I can't claim to know why he deleted it for sure.  I just don't think it's a bad thing.

Comment: @jin, realize that one of the consequences of deleting it, like a lot of deletions, is that now anyone else looking for an answer has a greater chance of creating a duplicate.  One of the reasons that we try not to delete much.

Comment: @Lance: Not to mention that a bunch of *other* questions *already* closed as duplicates are now going to be linking to a 404 for the majority of users.

Comment: @Shog9: Of course, would the original complaint about the envelope not working be still accessible, it would be a good place to point all those to who now complain about it being missing. (Note that I'm not saying that would invalidate the latter, but that it would be a valid and helpful tool in discussing things.)

Comment: @sbi: did you try clicking on it? It was undeleted a few months ago...

Comment: @Shog9: No, I hadn't tried, thanks for pointing it out. But it doesn't change my argument: deleting discussions deletes helpful tools in discussions. And I was discussion deletion, not the envelop icon.

Comment: @sbi: I agree, just pointing out the current status of that post.

Comment: @jin, one of the problems with them deleting the Eeeek question is that now people can't get the GM script that gave them back the envelope.  I'm fortunate that I'm over 10k here, and posted this link, so that I could get it today when I was on a new machine.  It really has so much more functionality than the dropdown.

Comment: Ajax bug on loading comments was requested for delete as fixed/no longer relevant by OP

Comment: @random, thanks for the feedback, wish they'd give you guys delete reasons.

Comment: Careful, this question will be zapped too by the crazed moderators.

Comment: @Shadow, I was just coming here to post that.

Comment: Never thought the moderators (probably only Jeff though) will act like complete bullies and hide their own mistakes like that. Well, so long respect.. but I'm here for the newbies, not for the moderators, just need to remember that. :)

Answer (score 20):

#### Discussing Deleted Posts

- [Deleted Questions Archive](/q/61221)
- [How do I view deleted posts?](/q/113752)

Comment: The first rule of deleted questions... ;)

Comment: (-1) for recursion (see my next comment)

Comment: (-1) for recursion (see my previous comment)

Comment: +1 for not actually making those numbers mean anything...

Comment: Wait, are you suggesting that this question will be deleted?

Comment: @Maxim, it seems inevitable.

Comment: @devinb That's not recursion, that's an infinite loop. See this comment for actual recursion. :P

Comment: Someone voted up the second comment, but not the third, so I had to do the opposite. See here for reference: http://youtu.be/ussCHoQttyQ

Answer (score 14):

#### Banning/Suspension

- [Petition to Undo Evan Carrolls Suspension](/q/60275)
- [Why my SO account was suspend for 180 days without warning?](/q/62687)
- [Why Was My Account Closed in SF?](/q/61200)
- [I am blocked from writing to msf, why?](/q/61319)
- [Stack Overflow Bill of Rights](/q/55230/)
- [Deleted a couple of my own questions and have now been banned for life from asking questions on Stackoverflow](/q/96102)
- [Unfair and abusive suspension because of asking for help](/q/114650)
- [Lets Put Our Friendship Aside](/q/199072)

Comment: Really? That was deleted? **Why?**

Comment: @Kop - it stayed quiet for a couple of days, and then a new participant showed up and it got a little ugly. I suspect some private emails went back and forth before Jeff deleted it.

Comment: @Kop: It's not only deleted, but locked as well.

Answer (score 13):

#### Humor

- [How Hard Is It To Build A Website Like Stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64972/how-hard-is-it-to-build-a-website-like-stackoverflow-com-closed)
- [Best place to meet female programmers (for romance) ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22795)
- [Does Jon Skeet cheat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81836/does-jon-skeet-cheat)
- [Why Does the First Line of My Question Keep Getting Deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94137/why-does-the-first-line-of-my-question-keep-getting-deleted)
- [Allow users to pay 2X of their own reputation to deal X damage to target user's reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127561/)
- [I Just Stumbled Upon Eliza Then Tripped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114271/i-just-stumbled-upon-eliza-then-tripped-and-fell)
- [For Those That Demand Those Elusive Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/for-those-that-demand-those-elusive-badges)
- [I Created Stack Exchange and Jeff Atwood Took the Credit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213704/i-created-stack-exchange-and-jeff-atwood-took-the-credit)

Answer (score 12):

#### Undesirable Behaviour/Users

- [Meta users becoming negatively infatuated with others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60220/meta-users-becoming-negatively-infatuated-with-others)
- [Very Frustrating User Experience?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/very-frustrating-user-experience-closed) (now on Meta Super User)
- [Is it possible that some users simply do not belong on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59463/is-it-possible-that-some-users-simply-do-not-belong-on-meta)
- [IncorrectInsulting Posts Upvoted and CorrectHumble Downvoted why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61508/incorrectinsulting-posts-upvoted-and-correcthumble-downvoted-why)
- [SO will never be the source of the information and enlightening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51752/so-will-never-be-source-of-the-information-and-enlightening-closed)
- [I just got a call from someone claiming to be Jeffery Atwood asking to talk to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49046/i-just-got-a-call-from-someone-claiming-to-be-jeffery-atwood-asking-to-talk-to-me)
- [Stackoverflow Glastnost, or: suspensions for joke questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/stackoverflow-glasnost-or-suspensions-for-joke-questions)
- [Ignorance prevails again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80467/ignorance-prevails-again)
- [Unfair downvotes reveal hateful bias among Meta users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69334/unfair-downvotes-reveal-hateful-bias-among-meta-users)
- [Who Will Rid Mods of These Turbulent Users Who Flag Questions Inappropriately?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58102/who-will-rid-mods-of-these-turbulent-users-who-flag-questions-inappropriately)
- [Abusive and Inappropriate User on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98061/abusive-and-inappropriate-user-on-stack-overflow-closed)
- [Why Deleting Good Programming Questions as Off-Topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135635/why-deleting-good-programming-questions-as-off-topic) (It's in this section because it's pretty bad behavior for people to close questions as off-topic, when (as per this specific case) they should have been closed as NARQ)
- [Racist negative votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161185/racist-negative-votes) (sounds juicy)
- [The Unofficial StackOverflow Strategy Guide by Evan Carroll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42962/the-unofficial-stackoverflow-strategy-guide-by-evan-carroll-pre-release-cooker)
- [Moderator's Private Message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181339/moderators-private-message)
- [SE Sites In General Helpful and Polite vs Rude and Elitist Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149687/se-sites-in-general-helpful-and-polite-vs-rude-and-elitist-behavior)
- [Is It Okay to Belittle New User and Students](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228297/is-it-okay-to-belittle-new-users-and-students)

Comment: More like threads where Jeff screwed up and deleted it to hide the truth, am I right?

Comment: I'm dying to see the contents of *"SO will never be the source of the information and enlightening."*  It looks like a treasure trove of abject whining and broken English.

Answer (score 10):

#### Discussion

- [Meta is becoming a sad and depressing place.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18135)
- [Examples are answers: use less to say more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52708/examples-are-answers-use-less-to-say-more)
- [Trilogy Portal Community Collaboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-collaboration)
- [Why Can't You Roll Out New Features The Way Everybody Else Does?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82692/why-cant-you-roll-out-new-features-the-way-everybody-else-does-closed)
- [MetaMetaStackoverflowology: Dowvotes vs Negative badges?  Can we have some consistency here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59454/metametastackoverflowology-downvotes-vs-negative-badges-can-we-can-some-consist)
- [Moderator Dashboard, Help Us Help You Help Us All](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72202/moderator-dashboard-help-us-help-you-help-us-all)
- [Stack Overflow Question Limit Makes Me Feel Sad, Can You Give a Guy a Break?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89600/stackoverflow-question-limit-makes-me-feel-sad-can-you-give-a-guy-a-break-c)
- [Quality of Standards Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/quality-of-standards-question)
- [Earnings of Stack Exchange per Month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96262/earnings-of-stack-exchange-per-month-closed)
- [Concerns About Zealous Moderators Makes Me Wonder If This Site Is Useful For Students](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108184/concerns-about-zealous-moderators-makes-me-wonder-if-this-site-is-useful-for-stud)
- [Favorite Programming Cartoon question — is not meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/favorite-programming-cartoon-question-is-not-meta)
- [What Stack Overflow is Not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/) ([explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is))
- [Is the language brainf*ck offensive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive/)

Comment: Student link asked to be deleted by OP.

Answer (score 10):

#### Feature Requests

- [Common feature requests that frequent the minds of SO users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/common-feature-requests-that-frequent-the-minds-of-so-users-closed)
- [Sort From Left to Right then Top to Bottom when the Users Page Needs to Scroll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81095/sort-from-left-to-right-then-top-to-bottom-when-the-users-page-needs-to-scroll)
- [Shouldn't Upvotes Obtained After the Daily Rep Limit Compensate for Downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29602/shouldnt-upvotes-obtained-after-the-daily-rep-limit-compensate-for-downvotes)
- [Key Performance Index (KPI) for Moderators: A Battle Against God Like Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93786/key-performance-index-kpi-for-moderators-a-battle-against-god-alike-moderators)
- [Allow Question Askers to Close their own Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally)
- [Make Displaying Previous Questions/Answers On Your Own Profile Page Optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74235/make-displaying-previous-questions-answers-on-your-own-profile-page-optional)
- [Can We Get A List Of Our Content That's Been Deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/can-we-get-a-list-of-our-content-thats-been-deleted)
- [Allow Post Author To Migrate Question From Stack Overflow To Any Other Stack Exchange Sites Without Other Users Action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167388/allow-post-author-to-migrate-question-from-stack-overflow-to-any-other-stack-exc)
- [Don't Close Questions Where The User Has Requested That It Not Be Closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)
- [Time Limit for Vote to Close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/time-limit-for-vote-to-close)

Comment: I Protest! *Eeeek* is and always has been a bug report. Hmph. (Sniff. I miss my Eeeek.)

Comment: @Marti, I agree with you, just forgot about that.  I'll move it.

Comment: @LanceRoberts They just deleted the feature request about seeing deleted content? That's probably my fault, I left a comment on Jeff's answer there yesterday (I believe). Do you know if there is a canonical answer out there in re: seeing our own deleted posts?

Comment: @agf, yep, one of Jeff's [most downvoted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297), another related good link is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator).

Comment: @LanceRoberts Thanks, I guess I've seen that but forgot, I only had the just-deleted one favorited.

Answer (score 7):

**Discussing Closed Questions**

- [Gnoupi Closing Non-Duplicate Questions as "Exact Duplicates" on superuser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60314/gnoupi-closing-non-duplicate-questions-as-exact-duplicates-on-superuser)
- [I was told there'd be no math](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9658/i-was-told-thered-be-no-math)
- [So Where Can I Ask Developer's Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/so-where-can-i-ask-developers-questions-closed)
- [Could You Explain What Closed As Not a Real Question Means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157444/could-you-explain-what-closed-as-not-real-question-means)

Answer (score 7):

#### Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow miscellaneous questions:

- [Is full disclosure of funding necessary in order for us to trust the content on Stack Overflow](/q/67320)
- [<kbd> elements are non-existent](/q/23624)
- [Stack Overflow Advertisement Gallery](/q/34181)
- [Answer to What Abilities are Moderators Given](/a/3788)
- [New User page - LIVE](/q/112151)
- [Will Stack Overflow's engine be open sourced?](/q/35)

Answer (score 7):

**My God, It's Full of Unicorns!**

(cross-posted from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45255/someones-going-to-have-to-clean-this-up/47830#4783)):

- [Someone hacked my account!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45118/someone-hacked-my-account-closed)
- [What happens if you throw a black gem at a white unicorn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45027/what-happens-if-you-throw-a-black-gem-at-a-white-unicorn-closed)
- [Sometimes my gravatar shows wrong picture, why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45014/sometimes-my-gravatar-shows-wrong-picture-why-closed)
- [Problems with my unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45004/problem-with-my-unicorn-closed)
- [Who has the best unicorn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44997/who-has-the-best-unicorn-closed)
- [Horrendous unicorn bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44968/horrendous-unicorn-bug-closed)
- [Why has no one realized unicorns have wings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/why-has-no-one-realized-unicorns-have-wings-closed)
- [My Little Pony cyberterrorism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44831/my-little-pony-cyberterrorism-closed)
- [I don't like my kornz, I can haz another one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44789/i-dont-like-my-kornz-i-can-haz-another-one-closed)
- [The picture on the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44925/the-picture-on-the-profile-closed)
- [How can I man up my gravatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45196/how-can-i-man-up-my-gravatar-closed)
- [How can I add Robocop riding my unicorn avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45007/how-can-i-add-robocop-riding-my-unicorn-avatar-closed)
- [How can I switch to a cuter unicorn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44820/how-can-i-switch-to-a-cuter-unicorn)
- [Why is my avatar suddenly a gay horse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45037/why-is-my-avatar-suddenly-a-gay-horse)
- [Why is my avatar suddenly a gay horse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44966/why-is-my-avatar-suddenly-a-gay-horse)
- [Should Unicorns be Proportional to your Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45015/should-unicorns-be-proportional-to-your-reputation)

Answer (score 6):

**Users Departing Voluntarily**

- [Meta In A Nutshell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32387/meta-in-a-nutshell)

Comment: the text of that was copied to his user profile.

Comment: ... hence [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18393), I guess?

Answer (score 4):

#### Approaching Deletion

(This is for questions that have a lot of delete votes.  It's hard to track them down after they're deleted.  After they are deleted, they can be moved to other answers here.)

- [What is a Bad Feature of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow)

Answer (score -1):

#### Badge Requests

(So now we're deleting Badge Requests, this first one sucks but it's unique.)

- [Badges for Registered Users in All Stack Websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96569/badges-for-registered-users-in-all-stack-websites)

Comment: yet again, OP asked for it to be deleted. Or, y'know, GLOBAL CONSPIRACY BY THE MAN.