# Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, fun

The system should search posts for the word "please" in proximity to the phrase "don't close" or "do not close", and if found together disable the close link for the following reasons:

- They asked nicely
- They knew enough about the system to understand that posts can be closed, and thus are experienced enough to know when their own question is perfectly valid and reasonable

Please consider this question an opportunity to consider the issue carefully.  I'll convert it to a feature request when `abs(votes) > 100`, until then it'll merely be a discussion.

Comment: But sometimes they're wrong, even if they ask nicely.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this proposal is fatally flawed. I mean, if they can't even be bothered to use "*pretty* please", how do we know they're sincere?

Comment: Bounty bonanzas no longer doing it for you?

Comment: I can't help but notice that you haven't explicitly asked for this question to not be closed. Voting to close.

Comment: @Popular I see no close votes, flagged as unconstructive. (NB: Please do not flag this comment.  Pretty please.)

Comment: Please don't downvote this into oblivion because `abs(-101) > 100` would be `true`.

Comment: Next you'll be asking me not to delete answers that include "I know this isn't an answer, but..."  It's a slippery slope.

Comment: But...but...it's not even Friday! This is an attempt to lose all of that "extra" rep, isn't it?

Comment: I believe the absolute opposite should be done.

Comment: @Tim: ["Pretty-please, with sugar on top."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZRUaDGW7WQ)

Comment: I almost want to upvote this simply for the brilliant answers it generated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't we close questions with bounties?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

Comment: Will it also search for Plzz?

Comment: **NOOOOO!!! Stop upvoting!!!**

Comment: What question prompted this feature request?

Comment: You have created slim fast for reputation. Amazing.

Comment: @AdamDavis **new bounty** :-P

Comment: w00t @AdamDavis I got the Necromancer badge ^_^

Comment: I think this post definitely qualifies you for the [chutzpah badge](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1133&bih=1116&q=%22south+park+%22+%22chutzpah+badge%22&btnG=Search+Images&gbv=2&oq=%22south+park+%22+%22chutzpah+badge%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=)

Comment: Any progress on this? We definitely need it to be implemented if for no other reason than [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem#comment93704_41976).

Comment: @PopularDemand I'm suspect the biggest impediment was Jeff.  So I expect we'll gain some momentum once he's gone.

Comment: @AdamDavis Beautiful mind :)

Comment: @AdamDavis Ekim is catching up to you... [he's currently at +3/-99](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142119/forced-retirement-for-top-users)!

Comment: I honestly can't fathom someone thinking this could work. Is this some sort of performance art?

Comment: @BradMace: This is very clearly a joke, and a funny one.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I would suggest that rather than closing these questions, we set up a migration path to Yahoo Answers.  To prevent it from being abused, it would only be available when the system finds:

> "please" in proximity to the phrase "don't close" or "do not close"

Comment: ...wow. That is *brutal*.

Comment: @camccann I think you would agree that this is a better solution that your very good suggestion previously accepted.

Comment: @Adam Davis: I am in absolute agreement. My solution was, I think, merely *practical*; this one is *art*.

Comment: Beware: This very question meets the specified criterion.

Comment: haha, nice idea, indeed

Comment: I actually favorited this question just for this answer.

Comment: @Dennis, They can't invent enough badges to satiate my appetite for bling.

Comment: Still, `1,515` rep, 2 bronze badges, 2 silver badges and 2 gold badges for a single answer are not too shabby.

Comment: @mootinator Congratulations, you've been selected for a chance to win this year's Satire Badge. It comes with a mahogobolony plaque topped with a goldenrod plating that symbolizes the Grate Audacity of satarists averywear. Upon winning, you'll have an opportunity to order a copy of your plaque for $55.99 + shipping and handling. Part of the proceeds go toward the Yave-Bin O'Conned charity to halp caustic typers find a cure for their aleness. Good luck!

Answer (score 111):

> The system should search posts for the word "please" in proximity to the phrase "don't close" or "do not close", and if found together disable the close link for the following reasons:

I think this is actually a good idea. Requesting that their question not be closed indicates that they have a solid understanding of what constitutes an appropriate question, in that they're clearly aware that they're presently asking one that isn't.

Given that, I think it's reasonable to grant their request and prevent other users from closing the question by preemptively closing it automatically. This will replace the "close" link with the "reopen" link, so I believe this adequately fulfills the spirit of your request.

Comment: Unalloyed genius.

Comment: ø¤A+++++ø,¸¸,ø¤º°`°º¤ø,¸¸,ø¤ºGREAT STACKOVERFLOWERº¤ø,¸¸,ø¤º°`°º¤øø¤ºWOULD ASK AGAINº¤ø¤ºEXCELLENTº¤ø

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: *slow clapping*  Well done sir.

Comment: Please ask this as a genuine request... I would support it.

Answer (score 52):

> They knew enough about the system to understand that posts can be closed, and thus are experienced enough to know when their own question is perfectly valid and reasonable

I disagree.  Usually when I see this, what they're really saying is:

> Look, I know this question doesn't belong here.  I really want to ask it though.  So I'll just ask nicely that you not close it, and we'll be cool, k?

That isn't the kind of behavior we want to encourage.

Comment: You made a typo, the `k` at the end of the second blockquote should be `kthxbye`.

Comment: @jonsca -1 What nonsense phrase is that; Everyone knows it's `kthxbai`.

Comment: I thought it was coythonksbee.

Answer (score 52):

This answer is not an answer, but *please* don't flag it as "not an answer", and *please* don't downvote it.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek, obviously, but where do we draw the line with this one.  It's more likely to be the people posting crap that are going to rail against it being closed.  A conscientious user would take the opportunity to figure out what needed editing and fix it.

Comment: For reference I got a flag weight bump for flagging as not an answer.  Because it's not.

Comment: @Daniel Honestly not sure what the point of telling me that was, but okay.

Comment: it pays to not listen to you!

Comment: This is the best one so far

Answer (score 40):

[image]

**This is an artistic statement, please do not downvote it.**

Comment: The above is slightly more tongue-in-cheek than you will think it is after you've read this. Also, this is not a comment, but please don't flag it. (also, apologies to both Magritte and jonsca for the shameless imitation)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm plenty ashamed of you.  Oh, oops.

Comment: -1 for beating that dead horse

Comment: @Won't: A fair point, I agree. Given the absurdity of the question I felt guilty for only posting a sensible answer like "automatically close it for them". This answer is, I think, sufficiently frivolous to bring my net useful contribution back down to breaking even.

Comment: @Won't ಠ_ಠ♦: That is not a horse.

Answer (score 37):

I'm having a hard time believing that this is even a serious proposal. I read your post three times.

[jonsca's satire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed/99064#99064) is spot on. This would open up a loophole for crappy questions so large you could pilot the Queen Mary 2 through it.

> ### Slushie flavors ???
>
> ---
>
> What is your favorite flavor of slushie?
>
> Please don't close this.
>
> [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [java](/questions/tagged/java) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

And now no-one can vote to close? Really? I assume that mods would still have the ability to close a question;* do you really want to delegate 99% of closings to them? That's exactly what would happen as soon as users who "know enough about the system" figure this out and start doing end-runs around one of the main quality filters here.

Someone who says "Please don't close this" obviously, as you say, has a suspicion that their question might be closed. There's already a way to make sure that doesn't happen -- write a good question that fits well on the site.

---

*If not, then I am absolutely incredulous.

Comment: +1 for "not sure if this is serious" *Most* of the questions that I see literally begging *not* to be closed are figuratively begging for just the opposite.

Comment: You made me lookup "incredulous" now for the second time...

Comment: I love slushies!

Answer (score 19):

In the end, you can never have enough jQuery ^_^

That **always** prevents my questions from being closed.

[image: when worse comes to worse]

Comment: `$('#answer-116145').find('.vote-up-off').trigger('click');  // it's really great and does all things`

Comment: +1 for the nice miniature image only.

Comment: @ShawnChin I prefer the alternative: `$('#answer-116145').find('.vote-down-off').trigger('click');` I noticed it worked in my console. :)

Answer (score 14):

> They knew enough about the system to understand that posts can be closed, and thus are experienced enough to know when their own question is perfectly valid and reasonable

Not really.

You'll also get "please don't close" from 1 rep users asking the same question the third time, after the previous two got closed for various reasons.

Answer (score 11):

> Please consider this question an opportunity to consider the issue carefully.  I'll convert it to a feature request when `abs(votes) > 100`, until then it'll merely be a discussion.

I'm glad to see that you really did this.

**Please don't convert this answer to a comment.**

Answer (score 8):

Oileee Oileee Oleioloooooooooooooooooooo....

Please don't downvote this!

Please upvote this!

Please see if you can repcap this answer daily 500 times, for badge please!

Please, yes? please yes!

Answer (score 7):

> They knew enough about the system to understand that posts can be closed, and thus are experienced enough to know when their own question is perfectly valid and reasonable

Maybe they're just trying to get a good rewrite going, and needed a launching off point.

Like refactoring code, but for questions.

Answer (score 6):

V fhccbeg guvf cebcbfny. 
Pyrneyl hfref trg hcfrg jura gurve bss-gbcvp be onqyl sbezrq dhrfgvbaf ner pybfrq.  Nccebivat guvf arj Srngher Erdhrfg jvyy nyybj hf gb xrrc znal hfref jub jbhyq bgurejvfr jnfgr gvzr ba Lnubb! Nafjref.

Please don't delete this.

Comment: [Rot13](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed/116168#116168)

Comment: OMG - That changed my life. Thanks so much. I never saw things that way until I read your post. I feel greatly enlightened. Ommm Almony Almony Almoneeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: I'm reading this answer for 2 hours and I started understanding it. I found Mr. Srngher Erdhrfg in Google.
   Please don't delete this thread.

Answer (score 2):

@Adam Davis, although they may have asked nicely, and are sincere in their questions, the problem is, they might possibly be just wrong.

They could be sincere, but sincerely wrong.

What you might possibly could have asked for however, would be something like, questions with "please don't close" be directed to the moderator's attention, for them to determine whether or not this question should really remain open.

In which case, just flag it.

Or you could ask for a feature which allows the system to search for such questions, to direct them to moderator attention, because questions that have to beseech users "please don't close" obviously need moderator help.