# Is there anything to be done about people adding disclaimers asking for their questions to not be closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've noticed recently, when viewing questions that have obviously been asked before, people spend about half of the question trying to explain how the question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate. It comes off like they're just trying to avoid the research.

Examples:
[Allow a user to edit the text in a UITableView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090102/allow-a-user-to-edit-the-text-in-a-uitableview-cell). 
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9057462/1

Is there anything to be done other than continuing to mark them as duplicates?

Comment: Ignore their comments and vote to close them. Eventually they will learn that their impassioned pleas are ineffective. Or they won't, and they'll end up with a low-quality ban.

Comment: Yes, except that we generally go through great pains to tell people that if they think their problem just isn't quite the same as the one already posted, they're supposed create a new question, link to the not-a-duplicate question, and explain why it's not. Now we're going to just close them anyway. If I recall, the "close as duplicate" was ***supposed*** to be a fairly rare occurrence.

Comment: there's a feature-request: [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Answer (score 8):

Edit non-relevant text out of the question. Leave in the bits that actually aid good answers ("this other question is different *because*...")

I went ahead and [edited one of the questions you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9090102/revisions), but left in a bit of relevant information.

Comment: But only if it really is a duplicate.  If it's not, they have a good reason to try and point out the differences.

Comment: I agree, @Bill, and that's how I tried to edit the question in question.

Answer (score 6):

Well, in this specific case I feel like they were giving an explanation, perhaps a valid one, for why their question is **not** a duplicate.  If this is the case I see nothing wrong with it.  With the overwhelming number of questions on SO it can be difficult to ask a question that isn't already covered.  Explaining why your question isn't just another duplicate might actually be *necessary* at this point.

If it was just a pointless "plz dnt close" then that's another issue altogether.