# moderator list: Anna Lear is missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) is moderator list on meta:

[image]

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/about) is moderator list on stack overflow:

[image]

Why are some moderators in one list but not in other and is Anna Lear not showing on none of them?

Comment: 20120206/BOLO/LEAR, ANNA/MODERATOR

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/welcome-valued-associates-anna-rachel-carleejean-and-charles/

Comment: She was recently hired as a Stack Exchange Community Whatever-it-was so she's a moderator everywhere.

Comment: 10-22 last, subject at work.

Comment: Something our [CAD system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_dispatch) might put out: date/time, "Be On the Look-Out", then the subjects name, etc. It was a yoke.

Comment: I never realized that before, It's [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) on SO, and [Won't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont) on MSO!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Anna [got job at Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/welcome-valued-associates-anna-rachel-carleejean-and-charles/) and hence is no longer an elected moderator.

Before SE 2.0 was introduced, all trilogy moderators got to be MSO moderators, accounting for Ivo and random (SU). Kyle and Joel got their diamonds for running the User Voice pages that SO used for feedback before MSO was created.

Comment: Why the community wiki?

Comment: Was ready to give the Adam Davis CW explanation...but you're not Adam Davis.  So why *is* this a CW???

Comment: @AdamRackis - Have you seen how much reputation I have here on MSO? There's nothing I want to put a bounty on and this needed an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Oh come on, Chris, there are many ways to shed rep on Meta - [get creatve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)  :)

Comment: @AdamRackis - I'm not *that* creative :)

Comment: @AdamRackis He's just jealous of my slim figure.  I'm still worried that one of these days Jeff's going to prank me by converting all my cw posts to regular then forcing a recalc...

Comment: @AdamD - I think somewhere Jeff's ears perked up

Comment: @AdamDavis That would be hilarious :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - especially given [this news](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html)

Comment: @ChrisF Just now saw that. Wow. :)