# Include section "Community Managers" in Moderator page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators

Yes I know this is some what duplicate of: [moderator list: Anna Lear is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121458/moderator-list-anna-lear-is-missing), but here I would say its not duplicate because my point/suggestion is different.

### Issue:

> [image]

By looking at [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) tab given on stackoverflow, I can assume these are the moderators only.

But being an active member since almost 3 years, I came across many other moderators like Tim post.

### SE employees who are also moderators:

Below are the missing moderators in above list:

1. [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)  (1st stackoverflow user)
2. [Geoff Dalgas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) (2nd stackoverflow user)
3. [Jarrod Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) (3rd stackoverflow user)
4. [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) (4th stackoverflow user)
5. [Tim post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post)
6. [Anna Lear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear)
7. [Robert Cartaino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)
8. [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)
9. [Grace Note](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note)

Click and check above users profile, every one is recognized with **Moderator ♦** tag but not listed in actual moderators list.

I know those who are listed in Moderators are actually elected by community. And those missing moderators are either founder/co-founder or community organizers(Tip post, Anna Lear, Robert, Shog9 and Grace Note).

### Suggestion:

There are 2 solutions/suggestions we can go either with:

1. Include all of them in Moderators list or in the moderators but with new section "Community organizers".
2. Include a new tab "Community organizer" besides moderators tab.

### Update:

I am not suggesting to include a special tab for "SE employees" because If you check Stack Exchange [team page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), many are having moderators right and many are not having. For example, [Michael Pryor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245/michael-pryor) is an employee but not recognized as a moderator.

Comment: Down voters are requested to leave comment/reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your original title is part of why people are downvoting the question - I edited it to make it clearer that you're actually suggesting a feature. But it's your call - *shrug*

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes I agree with you 50%, but you know that tight is misleading somewhat because I am not suggesting to include tab for SE employees but those employees/community organizers who are having *moderators* right, please check ***update*** part. Still your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, what about "create tab for SE employees who are also moderators"?

Comment: @Pekka웃 that sounds better I think. But what about to include separate section in the moderator page itself?

Comment: As it stands, I don't think this is a bad suggestion. I could see another section for team members right below the elected moderators, because they do have the same privileges and are active on the site.

Comment: @Brad Finally positive response after negative votes. Thanks Brad

Comment: As many people have already pointed out, the team page is where we list employees. If you see a person with a diamond next to their name who doesn't sound familiar to you (or someone like me who sounds like they're speaking on behalf of SE :), just click through to the profile. We're usually good about putting something in the "About Me" section indicating employee status and what our roles are.

Comment: @Laura Is there any rule which says you must have to write something in "About me" section?

Answer (score 3):

This already exists at **[stackexchange.com/about/team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team)**.

All of the people you list above are Stack Exchange employees - some of them are developers, some are community managers, others have other roles. Not all SE employees have moderation privileges, but all SE employees are listed on the page above.

Comment: This is what I have updated my question with. so my suggestion is to include all the persons who are having Moderators rights in the list.

Comment: Well, except Jeff, who doesn't actually work for SE anymore (although he is still listed on the Team page, which a link to his profile that says he's not on the team :) )

Comment: @Wooble Well, Tim post is active on stackoverflow. I saw many edits and answers.

Comment: Non sequitur? Unless You're saying Tim is secretly Jeff, which seems fairly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, [Anna Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155160/anna-lear) was elected as Moderator in November 2011's election,

> [image]

Later in January 2012 on she has join Stack Exchange as [Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/173001) that's why she is no longer works as Voluntary Moderator. This is the reason that she is not in [voluntary moderator's list](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Another Community Manager [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) also joined Stack Exchange at same time.

As she works for Stack Exchange you can find her and other employee in [team list](https://stackexchange.com/about/team).

Comment: +1 So there must be a section with "Community manager" title in Moderator tab, what do you say?

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes, It should be. Actually they all who work in SE are in [team list](http://stackexchange.com/about/team)

Comment: Yes it should be included in Moderators page or separate tab, because if new visits on SO visits moderator page then they may realize it has been running and managing by these moderators only, though there are many other moderators/community organizers are present.

Comment: @Lucifer - We use *Blockquote* format in images to display them with Grey border so it doesn't hurt our precious eyes. But what's the purpose of using Grey border on Grey image?

Comment: Hi Lucifer. I think [Tim was a more recent joinee](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/05/welcome-tim-post-our-latest-community-manager/) than [Anna, who joined early 2012](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/welcome-valued-associates-anna-rachel-carleejean-and-charles/).

Comment: @jmort253 yes, I realise it later on. I was in under impression that Tim Post is already a Community Manager.