# Meta's moderators are very shy

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, moderators

Post-split, Meta's moderators are (we've been told) the CMs and maybe a few other employees.  And, sure enough, those folks have diamonds.

However, something's missing:

[image: moderators tab is empty]

Where are all the moderators??

Also, while I'm here, see the underlined text -- I know it's boilerplate, but since Meta *doesn't* have elections, you might want to change that.  (Lest you say that per-site metas have that text too, at least their associated sites have elections.  Lest you say that betas don't have elections, at least they can aspire to do so in the future.)

Comment: Employees are never shown on those pages. This seems more like a feature request to make MSE an exception rather than a bug. (Also, we might appoint moderators from the community in the future. We're seeing how things go here first.)

Comment: Employees have never been the designated moderators before, but "feature request" is also fine, thanks.  And good point about possible future changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include section "Community Managers" in Moderator page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181475/include-section-community-managers-in-moderator-page)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that looks like a general request for all sites, where CMs *supplement* elected (or appointed) moderators.  Here on Meta they *are* the moderators, so it's a little different.

Comment: Well, CM's are not moderators, that's not their real job so I would just go with hiding that tab until real moderators are elected/appointed here.

Comment: So if Meta has no designated moderators (and CMs behave here like they do on other sites) then the current page is correct.  That wasn't the impression I had from the announcement of the split, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Why changing to support? I see this as a feature request to add mods to MSE, which was done hence marked status completed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my original question was that I thought Meta had mods (i.e. the CMs) but they weren't showing up on the mods page.  I reported it as a bug originally and a developer changed it to feature-request.  I wasn't asking for independent mods to be appointed; I've long wanted that too, but that's a separate matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, Meta.SE, uniquely among sites, has no designated moderators.  While the CMs (and maybe certain devs?) *function* as moderators here, they've been neither elected nor explicitly appointed.  On other sites CMs have mod privileges but don't show up in the moderators' list, so this behavior is actually correct.

**Update::** In November 2018, [moderators were appointed on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630/162102).  The tab is now populated.