# Why do no moderators appear under the moderators tab on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, moderators

When I click on the "moderator tab" at the user page on http://meta.stackexchange.com, I get an empty list. This is not the case on other SE-sites (I have tried Biology SE, Stack Overflow and Academia SE).

Screenshot:
[image]

I get the same result using both Firefox 38.0.5 and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: See also [How to view the moderators here in MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248317/how-to-view-the-moderators-here-in-mse)

Answer (score 3):

That's because there are no elected moderators on Meta Stack Exchange. Certain employees have taken up those tasks and won't appear in that list.

Comment: Ok, didn't know this. I just noticed that there are a bunch of diamond users (with the title "*(moderator)*" on their profile page), and no mods under the "moderators" tab.

Comment: Yep, those are all employees. So if you ever want to taunt a mod, come here and go nuts. They have no power here ... haha.... muwhaha ... MUWAHAHAHAHA ... ahem.

Comment: Good to know. To me, the empty moderator tab should then be removed at Meta Stackexchange, since it doesn't surve a clear purpose and can appear a bit misleading.