# Change text on MSE Moderators tab of Users page

Tags: feature-request, meta, moderators

Why is [the list of moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) on MSE empty? And why does it have the text about election?

> [image]

I've found this discussions:
[How to view the moderators here in MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248317/260198)
[Meta's moderators are very shy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230077/260198)

And as I can see from the answers, there are no elected moderators on MSE, only SE employees.

Can you change the text on this page?

1. If you are not planning to elect moderators, remove text about election.
2. Add link to list of SE employees.

Comment: bullet 2 should probably read: *List of SE employees that have their diamond enabled on MSE*. You can be an SE employee without having moderation ability.

Comment: You can find a list of employees by using my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304217/158100)

Comment: This also applies to Stack Apps and Ask Patents, whose moderators are appointed by staff despite being non-beta sites.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: Stack Apps' and Ask Patents' moderator subtab of the users tab both correctly list their appointed moderators, so this confusion doesn't arise on those sites. (One might be surprised that a graduated site is not large enough for elections, of course, but that's a pretty subtle point, and arguably neither site *is* in fact large enough for that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer relevant, since MSE now got its own moderators, as announced in [Please Join Us in Welcoming Our New Meta Stack Exchange Moderators!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join-us-in-welcoming-our-new-meta-stack-exchange-moderators). :)