# Non-employee Moderators on MSE

Tags: support, moderators

As far a small I know only employees are moderators on MSE so how is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) user a moderator?

Answer (score 12):

None of the four community moderators [appointed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630/162102) are employees.  Back when there were no community moderators, only employees with diamonds, [no names showed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230077/162102) on the [moderators tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) under Users, but now this community has non-employee moderators and they show up there.