# Can bounty be transferable?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Is it possible to transfer a bounty from one question to another question?

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: Just award another bounty to the other question. Why transfer it? Do you mean you made a mistake awarding it in the first place?

Comment: If you put up a bounty on a question, why would you want to transfer it to another???

Comment: I'm a developer for Stack Exchange, we make these sites run.  You still haven't answered the most important part of this feature request though, *why* do you want to transfer it?

Comment: Cancelling a bounty (thereby allowing you to place it on another question) is something moderators can do **at their discretion**. That's why it's rather important to tell us why you'd like to do it? We don't cancel bounties on a whim.

Comment: Even if there was, you're probably not going to get it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not possible for you to transfer a bounty from one question to another. Bounties are a one way street.

However, moderators do have the ability to refund a bounty, at their discretion. To avoid being used as proxies to game the bounty system, we don't do that without a compelling reason.

You have not indicated if the bounty has been awarded, or if it's still open. If it's been awarded, there's nothing we can do.

If it's still open, flag the question with the bounty and let us know why you'd like it refunded. Let us know where you intend to place it. We may ask that you place the bounty on the correct question first before refunding it - it all depends on the explanation you provide and the bounty.

In any event, your first step is to flag the question, select `other` and let us know what's going on in as much detail as possible.

Remember, we reserve the right to say 'No' to such requests, and very often do. That's why you should take care when placing bounties (which the system strongly encourages you to do).

Comment: The only compelling reason for refunding a bounty I found so far was to allow a bad question to be closed, which is prevented as long as a bounty is on it.

Comment: @Fabian I have dealt with very honest mistakes in the past. Rare, but it happens. My point is, they can *ask*. That doesn't mean that it's going to happen, but they can ask.