# Why was my question downvoted this much?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, down-votes

Consider Stack Overflow question *[How do sites validate you linked back to them in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198298/how-do-sites-validate-you-linked-back-to-them)* (now deleted)

Can someone explain why I received 10 downvotes? I'm asking what sites like mixpanel use to verify someone linked back to them?

I have never been this confused from a reaction to my question. I am speechless.

**Would it be a poor choice to delete and repost/reword the question?**

Comment: ***Don't panic.***

Comment: my guess is people only read the title.

Comment: Frankly the black hat comments seem a bit mad. The close reason is a fair comment however

Comment: rediculous. if i've never rage-quit, this would be the time.

Comment: You'll get -10 free credits around here.  Spend them wisely :)

Comment: I suppose this is simply too big a question for stack overflow. -11 seems an insane reaction however

Comment: See [this Meta SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason of the down-votes is simply what the tooltip itself suggests:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Since voting is subjective, I cannot say I know for sure the reason of the down-votes, but surely the lack of research helped. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site about programming; probably some users expected you to show some code, for which they could point you any mistakes done in writing it.