# Review Required Flag for Unjustified Down-votes

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I have seen quite a few items raised here about down-voting without comments but somehow can't seem to agree with the resolutions.

Yes, there is a message shown to the user (rep < 2000) every time they down-vote asking them to consider adding a comment. Yes, the reputation points that is lost on a down-vote is very minimal. But just because the amount of reputation points lost is less, down-voting without comments should not be encouraged.

I have seen points on why a comment shouldn't be made mandatory while down-voting. Those are also understandable. It is fine to not mandate a comment.

But can't we have a "raise flag" option (like we have for spam posts) where users with a certain minimum rep can request for moderator review if they feel that a good and credible post is down-voted for no obvious reason?

Comment: No, votes are anonymous, and moderators are *not* going to review such votes, let alone undo them.

Comment: We already have serial voting protection in place (multiple downvotes or upvotes), that is more than enough.

Comment: Why do you feel there is a problem to be solved here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters First thing first, I didn't know about the serial voting protection that you have mentioned. Is it available in the FAQ section? Second, I just saw quite a few unjustified down-votes which doesn't quite look right on a site where many privileges are associated with reputation points. 2 points is still 2 points lost.

Comment: Why do you feel they were unjustified? Perhaps the voter felt they were, but that is up to the voter.

Comment: See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829).

Comment: Because most of us could see that it answers the question, is not a spam and in some cases the person who asked the question even accepted that very same answer. I am fine with different people having different opinions, but say something like down-voting in retaliation to a critical comment etc shouldn't be happening right.

Comment: btw, thanks for the link :)

Comment: If the answer is correct, then over time *other* people will vote it up. The OP can ask, in a comment, if the downvoter wants to help out improve the question by motivating the downvote, but that's the extend of recourse the OP has.

Comment: If, on the other hand, we'd allow the OP to flag the post for moderator attention, the mods would *never* be done with dealing with terrible posts where the OP *really*, **honestly** feels they didn't deserve a downvote. That is **not** what Stack Overflow moderators should be kept busy with.

Comment: I understand that point, but that is why I mentioned that users with a minimum rep who are considered established and credible should only be given the option. Also it can be made such that just one flag doesn't raise an alarm. Say a min of 5 such users or something is required for it to go into the mod's queue.

Comment: @Harry A post doesn't need to be spam to be downvoted.  That it answers the question doesn't mean it answered the question up to the quality standards of the voter.  That it was accepted also doesn't change that; it just means that the OP has lower standards than that particular voter, or that the voter knows something about the post that the OP doesn't.  You don't even know who downvoted you, let alone that it wasn't warranted based on problems with the content of your post.  It would be nice if they helped explain to you what problems it has, it is well established that we cannot force it.

Comment: @Harry But there is nothing for a mod to do about the situation.  Unless it's a case of voting fraud (which this doesn't appear to be at all) there is no basis for the mod to invalidate the vote.  They are not there to judge the technical merits of an answer or a critique of that answer.  The intent of votes is that the community as a whole will judge all content, and if a small percentage of users attempt to vote maliciously or simply based on incorrect knowledge, it will be offset by the rest of the community.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the explanation :) I still don't quite agree 100% but I will take it for now. Will come back with a better suggestion maybe :)

Comment: You can use the "other" reason to ask a moderator to "review" your answer. But it won't do any good. They can't do anything about it. Moderators can't remove downvotes (or upvotes) even if they wanted to. And they won't want to.

Comment: The entire point of a voting system is to get the aggregate opinion of people who disagree with each other, while ensuring that everyone's opinion is taken into equal consideration. The whole point of having a voting system is so that what the _majority_ of people consider to be helpful remains at the top. If people can arbitrarily decide to nullify votes and unilaterally declare things helpful v. unhelpful, SO will sort of by definition cease to be helpful to the majority of its user base, and will rapidly become a tit-for-tat wasteland not unlike Conservapedia talk pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One downvote just doesn't matter enough for wasting the time of our diamond or 10k mods. -2 reputation just doesn't matter. Now, if a good, legitimate answer is getting many, many downvotes, this may be a case of revenge vote fraud, for which you can flag the post with an Other reason. That is something that a moderator *should* be looking at.

Comment: Agreed mate. I just now read the link that Martijn gave me. But a person who wants to retaliate and knows about this serial voting protection can still overcome it right? For example, my IP address changes every time I disconnect and reconnect to the net. I can down-vote the same person's posts not all at same time, but say 1 post a day. All are possible. But I like the flag option that you mentioned, maybe I will start using it going forward.

Comment: @Harry: It's account based. If there's serial downvoting, or sock puppet downvoting, don't worry. Flag, and let the mods deal with it. They have all sorts of tools and know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Harry: Just don't use it if one person downvotes a good post. People are entitled to their opinions, and the flag would be rejected.

Comment: Nah mate, I won't :) I genuinely understand the amount of work the moderators have to do because I have myself been a mod at a different site. Would deleting this question get my rep points back? :P

Comment: @Harry: Yes, but don't worry about it. On Meta, everyone has a downvoted question/idea or two. If you delete too many downvoted questions, you can get a question ban (although too may is really a lot ;) )

Comment: Yeah, but if I leave it this way I might set some sort of record for down-votes on a post. It is already 11 and counting :P I appreciate the time you Martijn and Servy have spent to explain though.

Comment: @Harry [You're not anywhere near the record for downvotes on a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed).  Heck, this isn't even the [most downvoted post of the day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192955/what-to-do-when-droves-of-people-hijack-your-question-and-interpret-it-however-t).

Comment: @Servy That is some consolation :P Besides, I will just have to be happy that SO doesn't allow rep points to go in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can already flag a post for moderator attention if you feel there is vote fraud happening. This should be used very sparingly, as the *vast* majority of downvoting is a completely normal and healthy part of the site. We don't need a specialized UI for making this flagging easier, as it should almost never happen, and would just encourage many users (old and new) to flag *every single downvote* cast against them.

You could argue that we would just up the rep-cap until we find the users who wouldn't abuse the flags, but frankly, by the time you've reached that level of reputation, you'll have realized how little downvotes matter and then *no* downvote flags would be raised anyways.

Comment: I am quite new to the site mate but the point I raised is not because I got down-voted or something like that. And If you see in my question, I already indicated that the flag option will not be available for all. Min Rep setting means that only established users would have access to it. But having said that, I understand all comments received till now. So, I will be removing my question right now. I just wanted it to stay long enough for Linuxios to see my last comment. Now I will wait for you to see this :)

Comment: @Harry You can't remove this question, answers have been posted... I've edited my answer; I thought you were specifically talking about giving some kind of flagging resources to new users who are getting slammed with a downvote-avalanche.

Comment: oops, is there any reason for it?

Comment: oh I see, so I may have to put up with losing rep points for a question/suggestion that I thought was useful and others didnt? :( ok just a question, what would happen if I raise a flag on this question?

Comment: @Harry If you raise a flag for this it will be rejected.  If you raise a lot of flags that aren't appropriate it's possible for a mod to take specific actions against you for abusing the system (it would need to be clearly malicious, despite being warned) or if not that severe, then your flag weight would go down and all of your flags would be at or near the end of the flag queue, rather than having priority.

Comment: The moderator would decline your flag, because it is a **completely** invalid flag. Downvotes are how people show disagreement with your suggestion on Meta. It's totally normal to have scores of -10 or lower. The only recourse you have is to realize that they're **imaginary internet points** and stop caring about them.

Comment: hmmm, anyways thanks for spending time guys :)