# Copying parts of others' replies into own replies

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-answer, attribution

It has just happened to me in the thread below that there was an answer which had several mistakes, and there was no reusable bit inside in the initial version.

[How to check the selected version of Qt in a .pro file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663331/how-to-check-the-selected-version-of-qt-in-a-pro-file/18663435#18663435)

Then, I thought I would fix the issue with my expertise and years of experience to get a useful answer for the OP's question. All fine, but once I did it, the person who provided the not so qualified reply (i.e. wrong in a few ways), began to copy and paste my idea and code.

Then I made it clear that this would not be something nice and appreciated by certain people. After a bit of commenting forth and back, he has put my name into his post with my ideas and relevant snippet, while still keeping some of the incorrect statements around. The end result is now a mixture in the reply.

How should this situation be handled, or how is it supposed to work? The consequence I see here is that certain experts will lose their interest because basically the reputation will come to the people having not had the work done. Yet, they would probably obtain the reputation. That may be misleading and incorrect.

Apologies for this long query, but this is a recurring issue all around. I somewhat became frustrated about bringing it up. :-)

I think a few people including me think that by now, they would rather not try to improve the situation, and instead: leave the wrong and incorrect answer as is, not to get into trouble. We would then just concentrate on writing our best reply.

I am not stating A, nor B, but would like to know how such a situation should be handled.

Comment: Putting smilies into your edited question isn't going to make it a better question.  Just sayin'...  :o)

Comment: I've seen you complaining about this sort of thing a lot. I am glad to see you come here for clarification about it.

Comment: I *think* many of the down votes may be due to disagreement that there is anything vitally wrong happening here. That said, this is far from the worst - or even most down voted - post on Meta. And votes/rep here are worth even less than on Stack Overflow itself, so don't worry about it overly much. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber in my case, my downvote here is due to disagreement with what is being said. The worst is over 100 net downvotes isn't it?

Comment: @uv-d [-155, here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) of those not deleted, that is.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yup, this is definitely not the "century's worst post", not even close.

Comment: It's frustrating, has happened to me, but meh. When it regularly happens 2-3 times a day I might moan. The flip side to your frustration is Nemanja improved their answer, which is what should happen here, so the questioner, you, me, other people, don't see a bad answer. You have 1500 rep, while doesn't excuse bad things if they are bad, at the same time you're not exactly a newbie trying to climb the early ladder needing rep. And after all helping out is sometimes a group effort :)

Answer (score 23):

There are a couple of things at play here. First of all, if you think the answer in its current state is a bad answer, downvote it. It's as simple as that. If the community does the same, it will be pretty clear there are problems with the answer.

Then there is the point of integrating your content. Is that allowed? The answer to that is "yes, with proper attribution". All content you contribute on the site is perpetually and irrevocable licensed under [a CC-BY-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). So you can't stop the copying from happening, provided that the copier provides proper attribution. Has he done so? Well, to a point. He does state "as Laszlo pointed out", which he edited in after a comment by yours.

So does that mean I can go around SO, grab an answer, and post it verbatim as my own if I just dump in some attribution? Technically perhaps. (IANAL) But the community will be pretty quick to kick my behind for doing so. Copy-paste answers are not appreciated and, even when correct, can expect their fair amount of downvotes.

So now the question is, has the author of the answer gone overboard in his copying of your content? My view on that is that he hasn't. In the way I read his answer, and the history of his answer, he has taken your advice and (the various now deleted) comments to heart, and tried to address the issues pointed out by you (in the deleted comments) as best as he knew how. And that is fair game in my book.

If you're in this game for the reputation and glory, this might be somewhat hard to swallow. But as the author of the answer says, he's not in it for the competition. And I personally take a similar point of view. You've contributed possibly good content. You will be rewarded for that over time. If you think something needs to be done about the answer, vote as you see fit. But other than that I don't see something here which should not be allowed.

Comment: A very fair, balanced opinion (IMHO). +1

Comment: @Tom But, shouldn't your voting also be fair and balanced, with a -1 included, then? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't know why, but somehow being called "fair and balanced" doesn't make me feel all that great about myself. ;)

Comment: @Bart: "Fair and balanced" is the epitome of journalistic virtues. (I come from that world, as a former economics writer.) Sorry if that comment doesn't please.

Comment: Just kidding @TomAu. Your comment is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I am the "person who provided not so qualified reply (that is, wrong in many ways)".

Comments that Laszlo put into my original answer (which contained the quick, but wrong fix of the code included in the original question) and on the question this morning were:

> In my opinion, this answer is not correct be cause the "qmake gens" are uncalled for. Also, the check used for qmake does not follow the standard we use in Qt. See my comment below what we use inside Qt. This should never be set manually!

and

> @Pietro: I suggest reconsidering the reply as the one selected is far from what we use in Qt, and it is also not recommended way of doing it to set manually, etc... in that way. It is not about accepting mine, but many users will seek for this information, and will be misled. :/ – Laszlo Papp 11 hours ago

As you can see, in his comment, there is no mention about what is wrong with the original code (the oversight of the `QT_MAJOR_VERSION` macro), but just the point out to his answer. I was corrected, and I corrected a lot of times, not by specifying my (or theirs) answer, but providing a useful information in the comment, and hoping that the answer will be edited.

On the first edit, I didn't mentioned Laszlo, but after breakfast, after he pointed that out, and after I saw that, I did included him a credit in my answer. Yet, his comment

> If you just copy and paste my idea and code out, I am not sure why you put my name into your answer with my work if you could only refer to my answer instead. The only consequence is that, you have not known much about the topic you were writing about, yet you get the rep and appreciation for someone else's hard work and years of experience.

makes me to understand that he and I sees the answering and the reputation system differently. What I've tried is to compose the original approach included in the question, and to provide an explanation why things should be implemented in the different way.

> Now, you copied my solution... without even a single thank you or appreciation, and note for the copy. This is very demotivating

And he doesn't think that writing a comment (that is deleted) about not mirroring much of Qt's knowledge without any mention of what is wrong in the post is not demotivating.

I've tried everything written here to put into the comments, but somehow, I think he is still offended:

> @LaszloPapp I can see that you have a nice habit to place nonconstructive comments on any answers different then yours. What "qmake gens are uncalled for" means? Couldn't you just add the comment about already defined QT_MAJOR_VERSION variable? That's what the comments are for. – Nemanja Boric 1 hour ago
>
> @LaszloPapp I don't see how my answer is far from the "what you use in Qt". You should only remind me in the comment about existence of QT_MAJOR_VERSION, and my answer, after the edit, would provide a lot more information than yours, as it is already well-written. In any case, thank you for the note, I've edited my answer to reflect that. – Nemanja Boric 58 mins ago
>
> You could explain what "incorrect mistakes" in the comment, without a need for useless comments. Sorry about you being demotivated, I will always give a credit for someone who noted the problem in my answer, so I will edit that. My latest edit is not me "copying your solution", but it has additional remarks about mistakes in the original OP's approach. Also, downvoting the original question is not the way to say "The accepted answer is not correct." – Nemanja Boric 40 mins ago

Comment: I replied to all incorrect in this post before the big clean up happened by moderators for removing everything. This answer seems to (probably unintentionally) distorts the complete situation, but I do not have time, nor ambition to write this out again. If moderators want to see the other side's explanation visible, probably they can get it back. If not, that is unfortunate.

Answer (score 11):

I don't come here for glory. I come to answer questions so that I learn. If your answer is correct, let it be. Over time, the votes will represent the correct answer. If the OP finds your answer to be the best one, it will be the one they choose to accept.

If you find errors in another persons post, leave a polite comment - but I wouldn't worry past that. Folks who see the answer can read the comment.

Lastly, don't get caught up because someone used parts of your answer. You are posting the answer for EVERYONE to use by putting it here. I would much rather that an answer I post helps/teaches/assists a hundred people rather than just the person asking the question.

And on a personal note: I would suggest that you see someone using parts of your answer as a compliment, not as something to get cranky over. I mean, sure it's nice to get credit, but if deep inside you know you posted a better answer, isn't that enough? :)