# Related questions with over 99 score display incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions, linked-questions, sidebar

[image]

The score for the 4 questions are 111, 1218, 261 and 5 respectively, but they display 2 digits per line. This is an obvious bug in design.

Comment: The padding of everything is kinda all over the place right now (I think). I trust that as soon as things have stopped happening the team will have time for cosmetic fixes without us enumerating all of them.

Comment: I've reproduced in other sites as well, just that right now I don't remember where..

Comment: @Braiam simply use the browser inspector and try to change a 0 to 9999

Comment: Linking to a [highly voted post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have?rq=1) so we can see a live example in the "linked" section here.

Comment: It looks even sillier for questions with a [four-digit vote total](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). Large negative totals [don't looks so great either](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed).

Comment: Looks cool if you set `#sidebar .answer-votes` `width:40px`

Comment: if it crosses 9999, the 5th digit won't even appear!! this is crazy. But I think even Jon Skeet hasn't crossed that score. _Allthough he has displaced quite a few things on SE..._

Comment: Same issue at [TeX & LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) - see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/31395) ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LmozG.png)) and [this meta post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4372/31395).

Comment: @AwalGarg Not quite yet, [but we're getting there...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)

Comment: @Izkata If answers were shown the same way, we would have been puzzled...

Comment: Somewhat ironically, this problem seems to also occur on [ux.se].

Comment: This appears to be fixed now, though 4 digits still [cause a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233606/small-overlapping-text-on-related-questions). Can't eat the cake and leave it whole! ;(

Comment: @ShadowWizard A negative sign and 3 digits (like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed?lq=1) question) also looks weird

Comment: And note that you shouldn't need to reinvent the wheel, [SO] works well with this already.

Answer (score 18):

I suggest taking some advice from the user-profile tags page in terms of how large numbers are handled:

[image]

It allows for 3 characters easily, with abbreviations for 1000+ (`k` for 1,000+, `m` for 1,000,000+, ...). Some consideration is required for (large) negative scores though. While colouring (say red) is an option, it may be confusion/not immediately apparent to users.

Comment: This has now been [formally suggested as a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239654/168244).

Answer (score 8):

The line wrapping problem is easily fixed just by forbidding it in CSS:

```css
.answer-votes { white-space: nowrap }
```

(Yes, the class name for those vote counts is `answer-votes`, even though the links are to questions, not answers.  Go figure.)

This mostly fixes the problem for three-digit scores, but four-digit scores will overflow the box reserved for them, and run into the question title.  For that matter, even for three-digit scores the fit's kind of tight.

As it turns out, the meta.SE style sheet *already has* rules for increasing the box width and reducing the font size for three- and four-digit scores.  However, they do nothing (in the sidebar, anyway), because they're overridden by other rules tagged as `!important`.

Just adding the `!important` attribute to those rules helps a bit, but doesn't really look as good as it should, presumably because those rules are really remnants of whatever earlier style sheet the meta.SE style was based on.  Based on some testing, though, the following rules look pretty good:

```css
#sidebar .answer-votes.large { width: 32px !important }
#sidebar .answer-votes.extra-large { font-size: 11px !important; width: 32px !important }
```

With the extra styles above, the linked questions side bar for this question looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I'll be adding the CSS fixes above to the next version of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), assuming that these styles don't get fixed before it's released.  Those feeling adventurous can go grab the development pre-release version, which already includes this fix, from the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js).

---

Ps. The existing `.answer-votes.large` and `.answer-votes.extra-large` styles *do* have an effect on the user profile answers tab, where these classes are also used.  Alas, it's not really a *good* effect — they just mess up the vertical padding for no good reason.  To fix this, the SOUP development version also includes the following extra rule:

```css
.user-show-new .answer-votes { padding: 4px 4px 5px !important }
```

Really, the best solution would be to throw out the current broken `.large` and `.extra-large` styles entirely, and rewrite them from scratch to look something like the styles above.

Comment: Looks like the first part of the fix suggested here (`white-space: nowrap`) has been implemented (here on meta.SE, at least; some other sites are still broken), but the width adjustment hasn't been, so large scores still overflow their boxes.